# Set runtimepath for vim in command line alias

Tags: bash, shell, vim, vim7.3

I want to set an alias for vim so that when I use vim I want all my personal vim files to be sourced. (I want to do this because the machine I use is used by everyone else, so I don't want to affect others' usage. The alias is also set only when I login into the machine)

```
alias vim='vim -c "source ~/.dc_dotfiles/.vimrc_dc" --cmd "set rtp+=~/.dc_dotfiles/.vim"'
```

But this is not working as files in ~/.dc_dotfiles/.vim are not being sourced.

Here are the contents of ~/.dc_dotfiles/.vim folder

```
~$ ls -lhart .dc_dotfiles/.vim/plugin/
total 20K
-rw-r--r-- 1 veveo veveo 18K Oct 18 17:34 abolish.vim
drwxr-xr-x 3 veveo veveo  19 Oct 18 17:35 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 veveo veveo  24 Oct 18 17:35 .
```

Comment: do you all share the same account on the machine? or do you each have your own logins, if your own logins why not just adjust  your ~/.vimrc?

Comment: All of us share the same account on the machine.

Comment: then how is `The alias is also set only when I login into the machine` accomplished?

Comment: I've created a bashrc in ~/.dc_dotfiles/ that will be sourced when I login and use screen. I've created an alias dcscreen which will accomplish that. (dcscreen will be used only by me)

Answer (score 0):

When I am using the screen I set a flag that will let know if I am logged in. I added this part to my ~/.vimrc

```
if !empty($DCSCREENFLAG)
    set rtp+=~/.dc_dotfiles/.vim
endif
```

If the flag is set, it means that I am logged in and using the screen, so go ahead and add the directory to the runtimepath.